# Trying to print intensive incoming serial data into richtextbox

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, richtextbox

I am working on a serial monitor project based on the arduino serial monitor, but with a lot of more functionalities. [Serial monitor UI with messages every 2 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScnmP.png)

There are 2 basic functions - **reading** serial data and **visualising** it to the **richtextbox**, **writing** serial data and also **visualising** it to the richtextbox. There is a problem when the communication is very intensive (arduino sends a line as fast as it can) and the user input cuts some of the recieved lines in halves. I made an algorythm to separate the input strings from the output strings in the richtextbox by setting sending/receiving flags. However this made the program act strange. Sometimes the command sent **to** the arduino just **doesn't visualise in the richtextbox**, but the data **from** the arduino is visualised just fine. I tried setting breakpoints on the user input visualising method and they were rarely activated. What is more I also set breakpoints on the visualisation of the read data method and they were also rarely activated. However the form was not lagging or freezing and the commands were flying in the richtextbox, contrary to the observed behaviour of the breakpoints. The printing algorythm is heavy, because I implemented multi-color printing.

**What I tried:**

-tried the blockingcollection approach. Just putting the printing actions in a queue and executing the actions one by one using 2 additional threads to the main one.(Task.Factory.StartNew). The problem was the queue was filled with over 3000 actions in the matter of a minute and the whole thing was lagging behind with like 15 seconds.

-i tried starting a new Task.Factory for every receive/send methods for every printing of a new command and locking the thread until the command is printed in the richtextbox. This is also too slow.

**Finally** I came up with the idea of just setting flags and allowing or not the print event. Using this approach the user input is almost never printed in the richtextbox. :(

**Printing algorythm:**

```
    void printToConsole(string print, Color txtColor, string part, Color partColor, bool isMsg, bool endNL)
    {
        while (print.Contains('\r'))
            print = print.Replace("\r", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < print.Length; i++)
        {
            if (newString)
            {
                newString = false;
                printTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
            }
            else if (i == 0 && !prevStrHadNL && isMsg != prevWasMsg)
            {
                printNLTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
            }
            else if (i == 0 && prevStrHadNL)
            {
                printNLTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
            }
            else if (i == print.Length - 1)
            {
                if (print[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if (endNL && isMsg != prevWasMsg)
                        AppendText("\n");
                    prevStrHadNL = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (endNL)
                        AppendText("\n");
                    prevStrHadNL = false;
                }
            }

            if (print[i] == '\n')
            {
                printNLTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
            }
            else
                AppendText(print[i].ToString(), txtColor);
        }
        prevWasMsg = isMsg;
    }

    private void printNLTimeAndPart(string part, Color partColor)
    {
        AppendText("\n");
        printTimeAndPart(part, partColor);
    }

    private void printTimeAndPart(string part, Color partColor)
    {
        if (timestamp == 1)
            AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), timeColor);
        AppendText(part, partColor);
    }

    private void AppendText(string txt, Color clr)
    {
        if (serialControl.ReadAllowed)
        {
            if (rtArea.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MethodInvoker mi = delegate ()
                { rtArea.AppendText(txt, clr); };
                Invoke(mi);
            }
            else
                rtArea.AppendText(txt, clr);
        }
    }

    private void AppendText(string txt)
    {
        if (serialControl.ReadAllowed)
        {
            if (rtArea.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MethodInvoker mi = delegate ()
                { rtArea.AppendText(txt); };
                Invoke(mi);
            }
            else
                rtArea.AppendText(txt);
        }
    }
```

**Serial read data print:**

**wait1** and **wait2** - flags. When wait1 is false there is no current user input message being printed.
    When wait2 is false user input is free to print. If the access to a print operation was denied it is performed after the operation which blocked it. (At least that is the idea)

```
    private void Port_dataRecieved(string a)
    {
        if (!consoleUsed)
        {
            newString = true;
            consoleUsed = true;
        }

        inputVal = a;
        if (!wait1)
        {
            inputAccDenied = false;
            wait2 = true;
            PrintInput(inputVal);
            wait2 = false;
        }
        else
            inputAccDenied = true;

        if (msgAccDenied)
        {
            PrintMsg(msgVal);
            msgAccDenied = false;
        }
    }


    private void PrintInput(string input)
    {
        printToConsole(input, inTxtColor, inPrefix, inPrefColor, false, false);
    }
```

**This is the dataReceived method from my serial controller class:**
    I tried several ways to read serial data and the uncommented one is the most stable one I tried.

```
    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    /*    byte[] buffer = new byte[blockLimit];
          Action kickoffRead = null;
          kickoffRead = delegate
          {
              port.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      int actualLength = port.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                      byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
                      Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                      string rcv = Encoding.Default.GetString(received);
                      dataRecieved(rcv);
                  }
                  catch (IOException exc)
                  {
                      //handleAppSerialError(exc);
                  }
                  kickoffRead();
              }, null);
          };
          kickoffRead(); 
        */
        if (ReadAllowed)
        {
            string a = port.ReadExisting();
            //port.DiscardInBuffer();
            dataRecieved(a); //Raise event and pass the string to Form1 serial_dataReceived
        }
    }
```

So, I need some advice on how exactly to print the multi-color messages without cutting into each other, printing every time, fast, with low cpu load (now it is like 35% on full load (arduino intensive transmittion) on i5-4310m). I would be glad if you could provide some examples, too.